# Inapp Restore for android corona sdk?

Tags: android, coronasdk, in-app-billing

In my application i used in-app purchasing.it purchased perfectly.but when i delete my app and again installed.its restore option return to failed state.how to get restore state or how to use response code to recover transaction restore.i searched over the net they told

```
store.restore()
```

this not working in android then how to get purchased item list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Google Play Marketplace, there is no "restored" state for items. All purchased items will be grouped under the "purchased" state. When you do a restore, you should clear all purchases saved to file/database — except for consumable purchases — and treat the returned restored purchases as normal purchases.

**On Android, you will get a callback with the state 'purchased' instead of restored, matching the first if condition below:**

```
local store = require "store"

function transactionCallback( event )
    local transaction = event.transaction
    if transaction.state == "purchased" then
        print("Transaction succuessful!")
    elseif transaction.state == "restored" then
        print("Transaction restored (from previous session)")
        print("productIdentifier", transaction.productIdentifier)
        print("receipt", transaction.receipt)
        print("transactionIdentifier", transaction.identifier)
        print("date", transaction.date)
        print("originalReceipt", transaction.originalReceipt)
        print("originalTransactionIdentifier", transaction.originalIdentifier)
        print("originalDate", transaction.originalDate)
    elseif transaction.state == "cancelled" then
        print("User cancelled transaction")
    elseif transaction.state == "failed" then
        print("Transaction failed, type:", transaction.errorType, transaction.errorString)
    else
        print("unknown event")
    end

    -- Once we are done with a transaction, call this to tell the store
    -- we are done with the transaction.
    -- If you are providing downloadable content, wait to call this until
    -- after the download completes.
    store.finishTransaction( transaction )
end

store.init( transactionCallback )
store.restore()
```